# What is the difference between "satisfactory" and "satisfying"?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "satisfactory" and "satisfying"? Sometimes satisfactory things are not satisfying. What do they mean? Do they both mean the same thing?

Answer (score 5):

Both words are similar in meaning, but each one has a slightly different focus. *Satisfactory* keeps its focus on the object that it describes. But *satisfying* shifts the focus a bit -- it focuses on how that object relates to others.

For Example:

> "This burger is *satisfactory*." (Sounds like something a judge would say at a grilling contest.)

> "This burger is *satisfying*." (Sounds like what a restaurant patron would say.)

The contest judge says it's satisfactory, because it checks all the boxes on his sheet. The patron tells the waitress that it's satisfying, because the waitress is tending to *his experience*.

So *satisfactory* describes something in relation to an objective standard, but
*satisfying* gives a subjective description of the thing. One has a more formal and impersonal tone, the other has a more informal and personal tone.

Answer (score 2):

*Satisfactory* means something is enough or accepted. On the other hand, *satisfying* is something that is up to the mark **you need or expect!**

Said that, if someone's performance is *satisfactory*, it means the performance is acceptable. If it is satisfying, it touches the standards you *expected!*

In the sentence in question, the author means to say that in some cases what seems satisfactory (acceptable) is not even satisfying (what you expect).

[Good answers are here.](https://www.italki.com/question/186228)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between these is the same as the difference between the verb "to satisfy" and the noun "satisfaction".

> **[Satisfy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/satisfy)** (v): Meet the expectations, needs, or desires of (someone)
>
> **[Satisfaction](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/satisfaction)** (n): Fulfillment of one's wishes, expectations, or needs, or the pleasure derived from this

To say something is *satisfactory* means it *satisfies* a particular condition.

> The tomatoes were **satisfactory** enough to put in the sauce, but I wouldn't use them in a salad.
>
> Her performance on the skills test was **satisfactory**, but not outstanding.

To say something is *satisfying* means it provides *satisfaction*

> It was immensely **satisfying** to the parents to see their oldest child graduate from university, as they had worked all their lives to give her the opportunity.
>
> The most **satisfying** feature of the new house is the enormous rose gardens in the back yard.
>
> The brief story you told us is hardly **satisfying** our curiosity.  You need to give us more details about what happened!

Comment: But google definition for satisfactory is fulfilling expectations or needs

Comment: Why are you just quoting the first part of the definition?  *sat·is·fac·to·ry, (adjective): fulfilling expectations or needs; **acceptable, though not outstanding or perfect.** "the brakes are satisfactory if not particularly powerful"*

Comment: what is the difference between meeting and fulfilling the expectations. dont they mean the same thing?

Comment: Yes, they do mean more or less the same thing.  You have to use logic.  Since the first part of the definition sounds the same for both **satisfactory** and **satisfying** you have to look deeper for difference in nuance -- in this case the difference between "meet a condition" and "fulfill a desire"

Comment: what about this sentence.  I did not get a satisfactory reply from Dawn when I asked her out.   this means her reply did not satisfy me. my expectations were not met by her response. or the condition wasnt met...huh?

Comment: @user236989  I have given you what I think is a *satisfactory* answer.  I'm sorry that you don't find it *satisfying*-- so I suggest you read carefully and not worry so much about what you think one dictionary says.

Comment: But what does it mean in the sentence that i just wrote above?